# adding percent of total next to numbers in data frame excluding 0 (R)

Tags: r

I have created a for loop function that will paste in a numbers percentage next to it in a data frame. here is my data and my loop.

```
response <- c("Best overall response", "Best overall response", "Best overall response", "Disease control(c)",    "Disease control(c)",    "Observed response(b)",  "Observed response(b)")
value <- c("Partial Response", "Progressive Disease", "Stable Disease", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes")
drug1 <-  c(0, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 0)
drug2 <- c(0, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 0)
drug3 <- c(0, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 0)
drug4 <- c(0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0)
drug5 <- c(1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1)

zero_ex_df <- data.frame(response, value)
zero_ex_df <- data.frame(zero_ex_df, drug1)
zero_ex_df <- data.frame(zero_ex_df, drug2)
zero_ex_df <- data.frame(zero_ex_df, drug3)
zero_ex_df <- data.frame(zero_ex_df, drug4)
zero_ex_df <- data.frame(zero_ex_df, drug5)
```

[image]

here is the for loop adding in percentages

```
cnt <- 2
### empty dataframe
df <- data.frame()
### for every instance in esc_table_df_cast besides the first 2 non numeric columns ...
for (i in zero_ex_df[3:length(zero_ex_df)])  {
  ### increase count
  cnt <- cnt + 1
  ### create new varible that totals sum of every column and divides by 3 (since this will always give us the sample size) and divides by the current number and mutiplies by 100 to get a percentage. sprintf if for formatting it adds the % symbol and rounds to 1 decimal
  new <- (sprintf("(%0.1f%%)", (i / (sum(zero_ex_df[cnt]) / 3) * 100)))
  ### pasting the percentage next to the number and appending to empty dataframe
  df <- rbind(df, (paste0(i, new)))
}
## transposing data frame
df <- t(df)

zero_ex_df[3:length(zero_ex_df)] <- df
```

[image]

This is good but not what I want. I need to not include percentages where 0 values occur but keep them for all other numbers. My attempt at this is as follows but does not give the correct output:

```
cnt <- 2

df <- data.frame()

for (i in zero_ex_df[3:length(zero_ex_df)])  {
  if (i == 0){
    new1 <- i
    df <- rbind(df, new1)
  } else {
    cnt <- cnt + 1
    new <- (sprintf("(%0.1f%%)", (i / (sum(zero_ex_df[cnt]) / 3) * 100)))
    df <- rbind(df, (paste0(i, new)))
  }
}

df <- t(df)

zero_ex_df[3:length(zero_ex_df)] <- df
```

[image]

As you can see this attempt does not work. If anyone has any tips / suggestions I would very much apricate it :)

Comment: You can always roll your own, but the Table1 package is pretty good, as is the epi package. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

1. Create `f`, a helper function that takes a vector `x`, creates percentages `p`, and returns either `x` as a string (if `p`==0), or returns `x` with the `p` in parentheses expressed as a percent

```
f <- function(x) {
  p = x/sum(x)
  if_else(p==0, paste0(x), sprintf("%s (%0.1f%%)", x,p*100))
}
```

Now, just group `zero_ex_df` by `response`, and apply the function across each of the columns starting with `drug`

```
library(dplyr)

zero_ex_df %>% 
  group_by(response) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("drug"), f))
```

Output:

```
  response              value               drug1      drug2      drug3      drug4      drug5     
  <chr>                 <chr>               <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1 Best overall response Partial Response    0          0          0          0          1 (33.3%) 
2 Best overall response Progressive Disease 3 (60.0%)  3 (75.0%)  1 (25.0%)  2 (66.7%)  0         
3 Best overall response Stable Disease      2 (40.0%)  1 (25.0%)  3 (75.0%)  1 (33.3%)  2 (66.7%) 
4 Disease control(c)    No                  3 (60.0%)  3 (75.0%)  1 (25.0%)  2 (66.7%)  0         
5 Disease control(c)    Yes                 2 (40.0%)  1 (25.0%)  3 (75.0%)  1 (33.3%)  3 (100.0%)
6 Observed response(b)  No                  5 (100.0%) 4 (100.0%) 4 (100.0%) 3 (100.0%) 2 (66.7%) 
7 Observed response(b)  Yes                 0          0          0          0          1 (33.3%)
```

Comment: If you are already using `sprintf`, I guess you don't need an extra `paste`. Maybe `sprintf("%s (%0.1f%%)", x, p*100)` is enough